# inner pages are not found error when change server name

Tags: ssl, twitter, amazon-ec2, https, server

Current server name and alias in my default `default-ssl.conf` are

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
```

and site is working fine but I am facing issue with [twitter validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) but when I change

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

Home page of website are working fine but inner pages are not working getting `404 error` and [twitter validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) are also working fine.

I tried with define multiple `ServerAlias` such as `www.example.com *.example.com` but still facing same issue. I have `ssl` on my website by `let's encrypt` and website is in `wordpress`. On `SSLLAB` I am getting `A` for my website.

Comment: What happens with the inner pages when they don't work?

Comment: `404 error` i get